# None of my modules work after Sublime Text Update

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext4

I downloaded the most recent update of Sublime text, thinking nothing of it.

However now when I try to run any code it wont import any of the modules, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
>>>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

checking the versions, Sublime is using python 3.9.5 but my Anaconda shell is using 3.7.6.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
>>> 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I'm thinking this is the issue, is there any way I can revert to what Anaconda is using (presuming that is path to least resistance to get my existing scripts to run)?

Looking online it has something to "Python.sublime.build" but I'm not really understanding the answers. Currently mine looks like below:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "windows": {
        "cmd": ["py", "-u", "$file"],
    },

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "cmd": ["python3", "-m", "py_compile", "$file"],

            "windows": {
                "cmd": ["py", "-m", "py_compile", "$file"],
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

anaconda python file path for me is "C:\Users\NAME\anaconda3\python" but switching this in for python above didn't work.

EDIT: this is the change to the sublime.build file that failed to work:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\Me\\anaconda3\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "windows": {
        "cmd": ["py", "-u", "$file"],
    },

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\Me\\anaconda3\\python.exe", "-m", "py_compile", "$file"],

            "windows": {
                "cmd": ["py", "-m", "py_compile", "$file"],
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you have a custom build system that you were using before? Sublime Text 4 uses the exact same configuration files as ST3, so nothing should have changed.

Comment: Did you install Python 3.9.5 recently? It may have put itself in your PATH before the Anaconda installation, so that's the default Python that's running. Also, please [edit] your question and post the build system where you tried to substitute the Anaconda path. That should have worked.

Comment: no i definitely had the later version installed when using it prior to the update. Didn't have another custom build system either. I posted the change that still didn't work for me (where python is saved in Anaconda folder on my drive)

Comment: ended up just uninstalling versions back to the one that my Anaconda uses; not exactly an optimal solution, however.

Comment: Based on your modification, you're on windows.. Thus, the top `cmd` is ignored and the one in `windows` is used instead. In ST~~4~~ the python default build was changed on windows to execute `py`  because the Python installer puts it in a place that's always on the path. You probably want to modify the `windows` version of `cmd` instead. Prior to ST~~4~~ it would have just executed `python` and not `python3` unless you had a custom build.